# How to use backspace as a shortcut in Nautilus to go up a directory or previous directory

Tags: nautilus

I want to set <kbd>Backspace</kbd>key as a short-cut that will either bring me up one directory (except for root) or will bring me back to the directory I was last in (which every is possible) in Nautilus.

I am using Gnome 3.18

Comment: possibly a duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/289535/bring-back-backspace-keyboard-shortcuts-on-nautilus-and-thunar

Comment: @val0x00ff - `accels` are broken as of 3.14 I think... so no, those won't work with 3.18

Comment: @don_crissti  I see. I was checking the wrong version. on my `GNOME Shell 3.8.4`    it worked.

Comment: @val0x00ff that didnt work for me

Comment: @don_crissti you are right, it does not work